# Screen transition - react navigation

Tags: react-native, transition, react-navigation

I would like to change screen in way so that user think it stays at the same page. Like modern snapchat, where screen appear from top and you think that screen is not changed.

How can I achieve these with transitions or something else?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I think you mean to use Modal

Comment: No, not modal. I mean screen...I try to implement from top but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at react-transition-group. You may want to wrap your <Route> with a CSSTransition. Then you will have control over the entering & exiting of components. 

Check the docs: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/